# Filter function in CLIPS

Tags: clips

I tried to define this function that takes multiple integers and keeps those that are different from 0. It does not work, apparently, the recursive call `(filter $?tail)` does not match with the parameter list. Can this be done in CLIPS?

```
(deffunction filter (?head $?tail)
    (if (= (length $?tail) 0) then
        (if (!= ?head 0) then (return ?head))
        (return $?tail))
    (if (= ?head 0) then
        (return (filter $?tail)))
    (bind $?result ?head (filter $?tail)) 
    (return $?result)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function filter is declared with 2 parameters `filter(?head $?tail)` but you are calling it with only one `(filter $?tail)`

Is the recursion needed? This problem can be solved easily with the function `delete-member$`:

```
(delete-member$ $?list 0)
```

Example:

```
CLIPS> (delete-member$ (create$ 6 7 0 8 0 7) 0)
(6 7 8 7)
CLIPS>
```

Comment: I don't really need this particular function, but I need a function that works approximately the same way. I only posted this simpler version to reduce clutter.

Comment: @PaulManta Then would replace the calls to `(filter $?tail)` with `(filter (first$ $?tail) $?tail)` solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something along the lines `(filter (first$ $?tail) (tail$ $?tail))`, otherwise the recursion would never end?